# How to retrieve EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT on result callback for rememberLauncherForActivityResult?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to retrieve what app the user chose after they shared content to external services from my app. The code looks like the following. I basically followed [Google's guide](https://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send#share-interaction-data) to retrieve the data except for using `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` instead of BroadcastReceiver.

```kotlin
val shareResultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result ->
    val intent: Intent? = result.data
    val clickedComponent: ComponentName? = intent?.getParcelableExtra(EXTRA_CHOSEN_COMPONENT);
}

// The below code is executed on click a button
val shareIntent = Intent().apply {
    action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
    putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, cacheUri)
    type = "image/jpg"
}
val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
    context,
    0,
    Intent(),
    PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
val chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, null, pendingIntent.intentSender)
shareResultLauncher.launch(chooserIntent)
```

However, the results are:

- When I share it in Slack, the `intent` is null in the first place.
- When I share it in X (ex Twitter), the `intent` exists but the `clickedComponent` is null.

One thing I am concerned about is that `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` is used in Google's document but it is not feasible [[Ref]](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/10437428?hl=en). Their document seems not up-to-date.
I use `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE` instead since it is required as the following error indicates.

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ${bundle ID}: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
> Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.

After some investigations, I managed to retrieve some information but it doesn't look the right thing to do for me. What am I missing?

```kotlin
val shareResultLauncher = rememberLauncherForActivityResult(
    contract = ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()
) { result ->
    val intent: Intent? = result.data
    val clickedComponent = intent?.getStringExtra("content_view_result:data")
}
```

[image]

Comment: `basically followed Google's guide to retrieve the data.` Well you should get the wanted info in onReceive() of your broadcast receiver. What are you doing?

Comment: @blackapps I'm using rememberLauncherForActivityResult instead of the broadcast receiver since it's in Jetpack Compose. Am I doing wrong and do I have to use a broadcast receiver?

Comment: I think you should basically follow Google's guide.

Comment: @blackapps I updated the code to use BroadcastReceiver and it works now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @blackapps suggests, I should have followed Google's guide in all aspects.

To get the information about sharing,

- We do have to use `BroadcastReceiver`
- We do have to use `PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE` not `PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE`

While `rememberLauncherForActivityResult` is still useful for knowing e.g. whether or not the user completed sharing, what they select to share is only available via `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: It would be nice if you posted the used code. I have no idea how you did it.